# are these two js async callback writing the same?

Tags: javascript

> Imagine you had 3 async functions a, b and c. Each one takes 1 minute to run and after it finishes it calls a callback (that gets passed in the first argument). If you wanted to tell node 'start running a, then run b after a finishes, and then run c after b finishes' it would look like this:

the example code:

```
a(function() {
  b(function() {
    c()
  })
})
```

would it be the same if I write like this:

```
 a(b(c))
```

someone gave me two examples:

```
function a(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('a');
        func()
    }, 1000)
}

function b(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('b')
        func()
    }, 1000)
}

function c(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('c')
    }, 1000)
}

a(b(c))  //get error

a(function(){  //work
    b(function(){
        c()
    })
})
```

But I still feel confused, need some explanation:D

Comment: The best solution here, is to use promises instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key concept is differentiating between function objects and invocations. Passing a function as an argument would look like this:

```
function a() {}
function b() {}

...

a(b)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
function a() {}

...

a(function() {...})
```

However, when you say `a(b(c))` you are not passing a function to a, but the result of invoking `b(c)`. The equivalent of that line is:

```
let partialResult = b(c);
a(partialResult);
```

The first part looks very much like what we have seen already, you call `b` with the argument `c`, which is a function. However, you don't call `a` with both functions as arguments, but with the result of evaluation `b(c)`.

So, why does this work?

```
a(function(){  //work
  b(function(){
    c()
  })
})
```

Because here you are calling `a` with a function as argument, and that function is neither `b` nor `c`, but an anonymous one, `function() {...}`, and that is a function declaration, not an invocation, so it is not executed until `a` says so.

So, `a` is executed, then it runs its callback, the anonymous function, which calls `b` with another anonymous function as parameter. The same repeats. Then, when `b` finishes, it calls its callback, wich then calls `c`.

That code is equivalent to this one:

```
a(function() {
  b(c)
});
```

Which translates into "Execute `a` with an anonymous function as callback. When `a` finishes, run its callback, which runs `b` with `c` as callback.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a(b(c)) means you call a with the result of b(c).

Calling b(c) means you are calling b with the result of c.

So you are now evaluating c to pass as parameter to b, then evaluating b(c) to pass as parameter to a.

Which is not what you wanted

Comment: thanks :D. but how the latter works? a(function(){  //work
    b(function(){
        c()
    })
})

Answer (score 1):

```
[1] typeof(c)    # Function

[2] b(c)         # works because, b expects a function and gets one.

[3] typeof(c())  # undefined

[4] b(c())       # Fails because c doesn't return a function.

[5] b(function(c())) # Works because b expects a function and gets one

[6] typeof(b(c)) # undefined

[7] a(b(c))      # => a(undefined) => error

[8] typeof(function(){c()}) # function

[8] a(function() {   # a expects a function and gets one
      b(function() { # b expects a function and gets one
        c()          
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you

```js
function a(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('a');
        func()
    }, 1000)
}

function b(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('b')
        func()
    }, 1000)
}

function c(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('c')
    }, 1000)
}

a(b.bind(null, c))  //get error
```

function a() expects a function as a parameter. but since you were passing b(c). You already called the function and hence would return the return value of function b. i.e not a function. You can do that by binding c to the argument of b and then passing this function with argument c to a. So a will receive a function, b will receive a function

Comment: would you like to explain why the latter works? thanks :D. 
a(function(){  //work
    b(function(){
        c()
    })
})

Comment: the latter works because each function is expecting a function as an argument which it is getting. It was not the case in your first example since the function b() was called and would return a non function value which was then passed to a